# Pass constructor with Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have one base generic repository and many class repository that inherits from the base repository. I need too pass string value to the generic repository.

Here is my Generic Repository

```
public class Repository<T> where T : EntityBase
    {
        private string SessionId;

        public Repository(string sessionId)
        {
            this.SessionId = sessionId;
        }

        protected virtual IDbConnection GetCn()
        {
            return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SalesDb"].ConnectionString);
        }

        public virtual int Insert(T entity)
        {
            entity.ChUser = "anders.persson";
            entity.ChTime = DateTime.Now;

            using (IDbConnection cn = GetCn())
            {
                cn.Open();

                return cn.Insert(entity);
            }
        }

        // MORE CODE
        }
    }
```

And the interface

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    int Insert(T entity);

}
```

My Class Repository

```
public class MarketRepository : Repository<Market>, IMarketRepository
    {

    }
```

And the interface

```
public interface IMarketRepository : IRepository<Market>
{

}
```

Now i want to pass sessionId to the Generic Repositories constructor.
How can i do that. In this case i have to implement a constructor in every class repository and pass it to the base repository. And the interface dont even know about that constructor.

Here is the Ninject bindings

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
    kernel.Bind<ILeadRepository>().To<LeadRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IPricelistRepository>().To<PricelistRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IOptionalGroupRepository>().To<OptionalGroupRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IProductGroupRepository>().To<ProductGroupRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<ProductRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IMarketRepository>().To<MarketRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IModelRepository>().To<ModelRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IOrderRepository>().To<OrderRepository>();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to a binding:

```
Bind<IMarketRepository>().To<MarketRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("sessionId", "Session ID here");
```

Comment: This puts the connection string to the "sessionId" parameter, which doesn't seem right. It's the correct solution for a static connection string, but a "sessionId" is not known there, as it's a runtime value.

Comment: It was just an example (using code that was recognised by the OP). I might update it to pass something random. Also, the OP doesn't mention how the `sessionId` is found. It could be anything..

Answer (score 2):

The `sessionId` would be a runtime value, so you'll want to pass it to the ctor when resolving.
The syntax to do that is:

```
var reposetory 
    = kernel.Get<IMarketRepository>(new ConstructorArgument("sessionId", sessionId));
```

Given that you don't want to use a [Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx), calling `Get` directly, and use ctor injection instead, you can encapsulate that inside a factory.

Configuration:

```
kernel.Bind<IRepositoryFactory>().To<RepositoryFactory>()
      .WithConstructorArgument("kernel", kernel);
```

Factory:

```
public class RepositoryFactory : IRepositoryFactory
{
    private IKernel _kernel;

    public RepositoryFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public T CreateNew<T>(string sessionId)
    {
        return
            _kernel.Get<T>(new ConstructorArgument("sessionId", sessionId));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var repository = _repositoryFactory.CreateNew<IMarketRepository>(sessionId);
```

Comment: This assumes that the `kernel` is being passed around the application.. which it shouldn't be. You need to do this close to the `Composition Root`. You can do it in Ninject bindings..

Comment: @Simon: indeed it should be, I was still in the process of completing the answer. I'm not sure how you'd do it in the bindings, as "sessionId" is a runtime value.

Comment: Where does the OP say it is a runtime value? Either way, it can be retrieved statically at runtime..

Comment: +1 for an interesting solution, but somehow defeats the purpose of DI, because the application becomes tightly coupled with `Ninject`. I would use the `WithConstructorArgument` approach.

Comment: @danradu: thanks. The factory would live in the `Composition Root` of the application, along with the other DI stuff and `abstract factories`. The rest of the application has no knowledge of the factory implementation.